# Django CSRF exception after removing clickjacking middleware

Tags: python, django, iframe, csrf

I need to fully load my website inside an iframe, so I deleted clickjacking middleware but after that, I got 403 code status and CSRF exception, how I can fix this to allow load my website inside iframe?

Comment: If my answer helped, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fully disable the middleware, you can disable it for a specific view using `@xframe_options_exempt`.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/clickjacking/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I really need to load the whole web app, should I use such decorater with all views? maybe there is something easier?

Comment: Then you should remove `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware` as you did. I can't help if I don't see more